# How to authenticate client at server using a hashed password with salt?

Tags: security, passwords, password-protection

I try to implement a authentification algorithm. My basic sequence for now is 
the following:

[image]

Right now i doubt that this is the correct way to do it. With the salt i want
to prevent rainbow tables but requesting the salt from the server would let 
a man in the middle attack get the salt and after it cracking the password with 
a rainbow table using the salt is easy.

Is the only way solving this a https connection or is it somehow possible 
to get it more save?

Comment: You should hash on BOTH client and server side but if on server side you hash with a random salt then it should be fine if you use a constant "salt/domain" on client side as described in this article: https://medium.com/@harwoeck/password-and-credential-management-in-2018-56f43669d588

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Never store passwords, just its hash.
2. Salt shall never leave server, generate salt and keep it as part of generated hash.
3. Use seed for added protection. Seed can be number of seconds from some predefined date till the date user created his login with the application.

C# code sample:

```
// extends byte[] to create SHA256 hash code with seed and salt of supplied size
public static byte[] GetSHA256HashCode(this byte[] value, byte[] seed, int prefix = 0)
{
    var salt = new byte[prefix];
    RNG.GetBytes(salt);
    return salt.Concat(seed.Concat(salt).Concat(value).ToArray().GetSHA256HashCode()).ToArray();
}

// extends byte[] to compare SHA256 hash code with seed and salt of supplied size to supplied hash code
public static bool IsEqualToSHA256HashCode(this byte[] value, byte[] code, byte[] seed, int prefix = 0)
{
    return seed.Concat(code.Take(prefix)).Concat(value).ToArray().GetSHA256HashCode().SequenceEqual(code.Skip(prefix));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i dont understand how it can be possible to not call the salt from the server but to hash the password correctly on client side. I never store passwordes, i just store the hashes. and i also have to compare the hashes only so i need the salt for a correct encryption.

Comment: You are only need to compare hashes on the server. Client simply provides entered email and password and server replies yes (authenticated) or no (incorrect email and password combination).

Comment: but that would mean that i have to transfer the users password to the server in readable text... not hashed? oO

Comment: No, you can hash it and send hash over, but then another hashing should happen on server. You should rely on server hashing as client can be easily compromised. No matter how good hashing is on the client, potentially it will be in the hands of a hacker.

Comment: Ok. I guess its better to use https so i dont have to care about it. i will keep the salt on the server. thank you.